Sending a file and a list of objects in the same request using axios
I've been trying to send a file and a list of objects in the same request using axios in my react js front and it comes out really weird.
I found a solution using FormData but then I have to use JSON.Stringify() on the list of objects and in my server side  (I'm using dot net 6 btw)  deserialize it. I wanted to know if there's an alternative way of doing that :)
this is the function in my react js front:
export async function UploadPersons(file, persons) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('personsJSON', JSON.stringify(persons));
  formData.append('file', file);

  await axios.post('...myURL...', 
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }
  );
}

and my function in the server side:
[HttpPost("GetPersons")]
public IActionResult GetPersons([FromForm] string personsJSON, [FromForm] IFormFile lib) {
    List<Persons> persons = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(personsJSON);
    ....
}

